# Panda Dataframe to.string with a decimal point (,)

Tags: python, pandas, file, export, txt

could you help me to solve the following task, please?

My dataframe has the following content:

1    BEN
2   BIIB
3    BMY
4    COG
5    GPS
6    HAL
7    IPG
8    LLY
9    LOW
10   LUV
11   MRK
12   PSX
13   RMD
14   ROP
15   STT
16   UAA

I would like to save the dataframe df as a txt file. But I need the txt output in the following format (separated by commas):
BEN,BIIB,BMY,COG,GPS,HAL,IPG,LLY,LOW,LUV,MRK,PSX,RMD,ROP,STT,UAA

I tried to use:

```
dfnew = df.to_string(decimal=str)
```

But that is not the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df` is `Series` join values by `,` and write to file:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(','.join(df))
```

If values are in column:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(','.join(df['column']))
```